# Android ActivityManager killBackgroundProcess not working

Tags: android, android-activity, process, activity-manager

I am using eclipse. I am trying to kill a process in my application. However, in eclipse it does not seem to know the hint for killBackgroundProcess from the ActivityManager and it will not let me proceed. I read that you have to have permissions to kill background processes and already added the permission which it did not recognize either from the manifest. Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcess(myProcessId);
```

Comment: The method signature is "public void killBackgroundProcesses (String packageName)" . Not "public void killBackgroundProcess (int processID)" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are targeting API level 8, as that method was only added in Android 2.2.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this then? should I use the process class?

Comment: @ngreenwood6: Ordinary Android SDK applications should not be killing processes.

Answer (score 2):

The method signature is

`public void killBackgroundProcesses (String packageName)`

Not

`public void killBackgroundProcess (int processID)`

The following is working CODE :

```
public static void killThisPackageIfRunning(final Context context, String packageName){
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
}
```

But this works only for >= API Level 8 as this method was added in Android 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is package Name not processId. Try passing it something like:

```
myActivity.getApplication().getPackageName()
```

as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your calling killBackgroundProcesses with the topmost Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these codes below,  it works for me .

```
public static void clearMemory(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManger = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = activityManger.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (list != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo apinfo = list.get(i);

                String[] pkgList = apinfo.pkgList;

                if (apinfo.importance > ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_PERCEPTIBLE ) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < pkgList.length; j++) {
                        activityManger.killBackgroundProcesses(pkgList[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```