# Kill other application on Android

Tags: android, kill-process

I know this question was asked a lot of times, and I think i read all relevant threads, all saying that android app can't kill another app, unless they both have the same user id (BTW, how can two applications have the same UID, isn't a unique id that application gets when it's installed?)
BUT, i recently installed avast! on my device and used their app locker feature.
by running ps, from adb shell, i can see that when avast! block my application, they are also killing the process.

The device is not rooted, the application doesn't ask for device administration, they don't ask for any special permission (except of course, to kill background apps), so I wonder, how can they kill my application process if we don't share the same uid?

I tried using ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName), but nothing happens, the application i'm trying to kill, is not killed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your minimum API level? Also, post your code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not at home, so i can't check, but i think i tried that with minimum API 18 (what should it be?). i tried running ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.my.pacakge") (where com.my.package is the package name of the application i want to kill

Comment: This function was only added in API level 8. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String)

Comment: so for sure i'm using an higher api level. anyway, the problem is that the API called, but doesn't do anything (or at least doesn't kill the app)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/q/3643872/1064310

Comment: not sure what you meant me to see, but that's exactly what i've done: ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);

Comment: you can avoid open another from you app by using package name